# Partitioned domain for scratch orgs suddenly rolled back

Tags: scratch-org, enhanced-domains

On October 2022, our instance (DevHub) was upgraded such as that new scratch orgs were created using [partitioned domains](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_partitioned_domains_scratch.htm&type=5). We then adjusted all our internal mappings to include the extra `.scratch` on each URL.

Now, the only 'interesting event' I can think of is that at the beginning of this year our instance was moved to Hyperforce and all of sudden our scratch orgs are created again without `.scratch`, is this expected? I can't find anywhere in the documentation how Hyperforce can affect partitioned domains. Maybe it's unrelated to Hyperforce but I also don't see any announcement of `.scratch` being rolled back or so. Is anyone facing the same?

For now we're just mapping both URL formats but would be great to know what's the actual final scratch org format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior that you observe is indeed related to Hyperforce:

I was experiencing the same in my scratch orgs. Salesforce documentation states [New scratch orgs are partitioned by default](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_partitioned_domains_scratch.htm&type=5) and it doesn't mention anything about it not being available in hyperforce.

I decided to reach out to Salesforce support and they came back with this answer:

> Upon checking this with the 'Enhanced Domain' R&D team, it has been confirmed that currently we do not have partitioned "My Domains" available in Hyperforce instances. It is in the process of being rolled out and would likely be enabled within a couple of months.

I'm still waiting for a more specific timeline but at least we know why our scratch orgs don't have partitioned domains!

Comment: Oh, so does that mean that `.scratch` will pop up again in our scratch orgs at some point? did they give you a timeline or link to docs? Anyway, thanks for confirming!

Comment: No specific timeline yet but I did get the following reply:

"The following documentation mentions that 'partitioned domains' can be available before Summer '23 release without mentioning the details of the type of instance (Hyperforce or not).
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_partitioned_domains.htm&type=5"